# React import error, element type is invalid?

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-agnesi-29zq8 Why is this sandbox getting this error all of a sudden:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

It was working before and I did not play with any import app names? How can I fix. I've searched other stack overflow questions with similar titles but they werent able to solve this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `ToggleButton`, `ToggleButtonGroup` and `Pagination` are not from the **core** Material UI library, they're from the **lab** library. So you need to add the `@material-ui/lab` dependency and then import those 3 from there. So it'd be like this:

```
import {
  Box,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardHeader,
  Grid,
  Container,
  Chip
} from "@material-ui/core/";

import {
  ToggleButtonGroup,
  ToggleButton,
  Pagination
} from "@material-ui/lab/";

...
```

[I tweaked your sandbox here to show this](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-meadow-5sqiy?file=/src/App.js)